# mysql, resultset and listtt

Tags: java, mysql, list, resultset

I wrote this code that reads data from Mysql database:

```
List<user> AllUsers = new ArrayList<user>();
private static Connection conn;
conn=Driver.Manager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql.....");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table");
while(rs.next()){
    user u = new user();
    u.id = rs.getInt("id");
    u.name = rs.getString("name");
    u.address = rs.getString("address");
    AllUsers.add(u);
}
return AllUsers;
```

however, i always get AllUsers full with data but all datas are the same-last read
data from database. how to get all datas not just last read wrote in AllUsers again and again.... tnx

Comment: no, i didnt it the only way i managed to wrote it here, otherwise i always get some error messages....

Answer (score 0):

not a full answer, but couple of glitch fixing things that could help, System.out.println(); the results as it transverses the table, will tell you if the data is even being passed in correctly.

Also, check the ResultSet using some of the methods described here [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) to test to see if the table is comming in.

Lastly check your table on the server side to make sure it was created properly as well. You might just have a table of same/same/same data.